Fourth species counterpoint treating fourth

I'm so confused why does in fux book he treats the P4 as a consonance and leaps from it instead of resolving it down to a third( measure 7 )
Also how common is going above the cantuse firmus in counterpoint?
Can just cross the cantus firmus for a few times in an exercise ?

There is no perfect fourth here.  The lower part has been transcribed to octave transposing treble clef, so the first two pitches are D3 and D4, followed by C4, B3, E4, etc.  Note the small 8 at the bottom of the clef sign; also notice that the original clefs are given, with the lower part being in tenor clef and the upper in alto clef.
The upper part has been transcribed to "normal" treble clef, so the pitches are D4, F4, E4, D4, etc.  The highlighted notes form an octave with the upper voice, then a minor tenth, then a minor third.
Starting in measure 6, the intervals are minor second, minor third, perfect fifth, major third, etc.
It looks as though you have missed the fact that the lower part is to be transposed down an octave, because if it isn't then the perfect fifth would be a perfect fourth. That would also explain your question about the lower part being above the cantus firmus.  It's not unusual for the there to be one or more parts above the cantus firmus, but those parts will normally be placed above the cantus firmus on the page.

This is most certainly the case.  Watch those clefs!

I had no idea about the 8 under the cleff . Thanks
